# JQuery assigning a newly created link to a variable?

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink, html-table

How do I assign this newly created link to the local variable?

```
tblOutput += '<td>';

tblOutput += $('<a></a>')
    .click(function (e) {
        $.fancybox({ 'autoDimension': true, 'showCloseButton': true, 'type': 'iframe', 'href': 'WordManagerForm.aspx?cmd=updateword&amp;categoryNodeID=' + nodeID + '&amp;nodeID=' + id_text });
            e.preventDefault();
        })
    .css('color', 'Blue')
    .text(name_text);


tblOutput += '</td>';
```

I have tried applying `.html()` after `.text(name_text)` but that only prints the text out and not the active link. How can I get the link to work? After I have gone thru the loop I add the variable tblOutput to a div using `$('#divOut').html(tblOutput);`

It worked when I assigned it to an element with an id, like `<div id="test"...>` and then `.text(name_text).appendTo('#test');`.

Full loop:

```
$(xml).find('word').each(function () {                        
                    var id_text = $(this).attr('id');
                    var name_text = $(this).attr('name');
                    var translation_text = $(this).attr('translation');

                    $('<a></a>')
                         .click(function (e) {
                             $.fancybox({ 'autoDimension': true, 'showCloseButton': true, 'type': 'iframe', 'href': 'WordManagerForm.aspx?cmd=updateword&amp;categoryNodeID=' + nodeID + '&amp;nodeID=' + id_text });
                             e.preventDefault();
                         })
                         .css('color', 'Blue')
                         .text(name_text)
                         .appendTo('#bottomRight');
                    $('<br>').appendTo('#bottomRight');
                });
```

Comment: Can you post the complete loop? You have to add the elements together in a document fragment, not treat then as an HTML string if you want to do what you're after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to build the table as elements rather than a HTML string here...I can't say *exactly* what it would be without seeing your outer loop, but here's the general idea:

```
//row loop...
var row = $("<tr></tr>");

  //create cells here...
  var cell = $("<td></td>");
  $('<a></a>')
    .click(function (e) {
        $.fancybox({ 'autoDimension': true, 'showCloseButton': true, 'type': 'iframe', 'href': 'WordManagerForm.aspx?cmd=updateword&amp;categoryNodeID=' + nodeID + '&amp;nodeID=' + id_text });
            e.preventDefault();
        })
    .css('color', 'Blue')
    .text(name_text)
    .appendTo(cell);
  cell.appendTo(row);
  //end cell loop

row.appendTo('#myTable');
//end row loop
```

Or if you're creating the entire table, create that as an element as well, then append the whole table to the DOM at once, since appending to the DOM is a relatively expensive operation.

Comment: This is how i had it before i started mixing the tables (see above). What i wanted to do was to wrap the entire loop into a table. There would be 2 columns in each iteration. One with the link and one with the translation_text variable.

Answer (score 0):

to get the outer html of an element (*including the same*) you need to wrap it inside another and get the html of the wrapper..

so

```
.text(name_text)
```

should change to

```
.text(name_text).wrap('div').parent().html()
```

but <strike>the css applied with jquery and</strike> the click event will not be there once you add that string in the dom, because you seem to be storing everything as a string and then adding that to the DOM.. (*the moment you convert a jquery object to its string equivalent, you loose all DOM <strike>dynamic changes to properties (with `.css()`) and all</strike> events attached..*)

Comment: This isn't *quite* accurate, styling information *will* be carried on when it's output with `.html()`, you can see a quick example here: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/pcZb8/

Comment: @Gert - It won't....you changed the premise, you're passing jQuery object into `.html()` not the string, which looks like this: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/pcZb8/1/ (notice no click).  When you do `.html(jQueryElement)` you're *really* doing `.empty().append(jQueryElement)`, so it's a different situation.

Comment: @Nick Craver - Oops... I was simplifying it a bit too much. You're right... The output becomes "[object Object]" (at least in FF). Deleted my comment. You're a good teacher, Nick.

Comment: @Nick, the OP is taking the raw output, appending it to a string and then re-adds this string to the DOM .. no styling from his code will be retained.. if he uses the created object to add it, i agree, it will create the events and styles.. but not if he takes the html representation of it.. like this http://jsfiddle.net/hrGcs/

Comment: @Gaby - Again that's not the HTML representation *of it*, that's the HTML representation *of its contents*, which is a different thing :) Taking its HTML would be like this, notice styling is retained, the `style="color: blue;"` is in the `<a>` tag: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/hrGcs/1/  Your answer says "it's string equivalent"....your example isn't its string equivalent, the string of it's *children* is a different matter :)

Comment: @Nick, indeed.. you are correct.. i did not use the actual answer i provided in wrapping the content with another element and taking that ones html ... thanks for pointing that out ! (*answer updated*)